# "range out of order in character class" in PHP regex?

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to get this work for a while but in vain.
I want to create a php regex to check if a string has atleast one number and atleast one of the symbols amongst ( _-+=*& )

This is my regex

```
 $result = preg_match('/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[_-+=*&]).{3,}$/',$pass);
```

I get the following error 
       Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Compilation failed: range out of order in character          class       at offset 17 in myfile.php on line 8

any help ?

Comment: For reference: "regex" is short for "regular expression".  Making "regex expression" short for "regular expression expression".</pedantry>  :)

Comment: `_-+` is wrong. What does `-` do in a character class (`[..]`)?

Comment: To further @pst's remark:  The `-` in `_-+` is the 17th character.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `-` needs to be escaped, or placed at the start / end of the `[...]` list:

```
$result = preg_match('/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[-_+=*&]).{3,}$/',$pass);
```

If you don't, `-` is interpreted as the range operator and if `x > y` in `[x-y]` you get that error.

Answer (score 0):

I used `/u` in the end of my pattern when I get this *Warning*. Just try it.
It means **Ungreedy pattern**

```
$pattern = "^([ `anything` ])$/u";
```

Comment: What question are you answering?